# Is there a way to get importer's variable in importee?

Tags: python

Say that I have two python file

```
 # importer.py
 parameter = 4
 import importee
```

and

```
 # importee.py
 print parameter
```

Can I or how can I in **importee.py** access **importer.py**'s `parameter`?

I'm using an ugly work around, borrow (and pollute) the `sys`

```
 # importer.py
 import sys
 sys.parameter = 4
 import importee
```

and

```
 # importee.py
 print sys.parameter
```

Too ugly.
Looking for better solution.

Comment: That would result in a circular import which is usually the sign of a design problem. Why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: @IanAuld As in my example, I hope to import the **importee** module with some "parameter".

Comment: what do you plan on doing with it?

Comment: I see what you want to do, I'm just not sure why you need to. If you need to use this variable in more than one file it may be prudent to move it to a config file.

Comment: You could call a method, which sets a static variable in the importee class.

Comment: You want a config file, as people are telling you. No need to overcomplicate things, you only want to import static parameter definitions, you don't need to define accessor functions.

Comment: If importer and importee both need to access the same set of config parameters, that's a code smell that those parameters should be stored together. Or at least change your import order of hierarchy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recommended way to achieve what I think you want to achieve is to declare function in importee, and call it, e.g.:

```
# importer.py
import importee
importee.call_me(4)
```

and:

```
# importee.py
def call_me(parameter):
    print(parameter)
```

It is preferable to avoid performing any operations in global scope. And especially `print()`ing anything but I suppose your minimal example doesn't match your real use case :).

---

By the way, the ugly work around you have mentioned is practically equivalent to using a separate configuration module. For example:

```
# importer.py
import config
config.param = 4
import importee
```

+

```
# importee.py
import config
print(config.param)
```

+

```
# config.py
param = 7 # some default
```

It's still nowhere close to pretty but at least avoids mangling with system modules.

Comment: +1 for giving the two different and reasonable options (IMHO). I find the ``import config`` approach quite nice, and in some scenarios it can be life-saving. Only when the first recommended way is not possible, ofc.

Comment: Loving your both solution. Picking the first one. Thanks a lot!